# Django - For the html in the subdirectory /snippets in accounts - TemplateDoesNotExist at /friend_request/user_id/

Tags: python, django

I am facing an error that is very common, if the template directory is not assigned in the TEMPLATES in settings.py

The problem ist, that the app overall works and I get the error "TemplateDoesNotExist at /friend_request/user_id/" when I want to access an .html file in a subdirectory.

Here the Settings.py TEMPLATES

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'accounts/templates/accounts')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

I assigned the proper context, getting passed to the sociel.html file containing the link to my friend_requests.html file in the subdirectory /snippets

here the view in views.py

```
def friend_requests(request, *args, **kwargs):
context = {}
user = request.user
user_id = None
friend_requests = None
if user.is_authenticated:
    user_id = user.pk
    account = Account.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    if account == user:
        friend_requests = FriendRequest.objects.filter(receiver=account, is_active=True)
        context['friend_requests'] = friend_requests
    else:
        return HttpResponse("You can't ciew another users fried requests.")
else:
    redirect("login")
return render(request, "friend_requests.html", context)
```

and here the reference in social.html

```
<a href="{% url 'friend_requests' 'user_id' %}"><p id="rd_contact">Requests</p></a>
```

the reference in urls.py looks like this

```
path('friend_request/<user_id>/', views.friend_requests, name='friend_requests'),
```

About the structure of my directories.

```
|templates
 |accounts
  |snippets
   |friend_request.html
  |social.html(containing link to friend_request
```

When I move my friend_request.html one directory up, into the accounts directory, the link works and I get the page I want to. But for the structure, i'd like friend_request.html in the subdir.

so the Problem is not, that the variables, I give to the social.html are not working but that the link does not search in the subdir containing the friend_request.html

I hope that makes my intention clear.

The variable from the views.py is hardcoded but could also be accessed over {% url 'friend_requests' user.pk %}
But since I have an other redirect("login") if no user is authenticated this integer should be passed over by the views.py

```
if user.is_authenticated:
    user_id = user.pk
    ...
else:
    redirect("login")
```

I already found one contribution here on stackflow that described a similar problem, that did not answered my problem

Comment: Your urls.py is looking for a variable called ```<user_id```, but you are passing string ```'user_id'``` from ```"{% url 'friend_requests' 'user_id' %}"```.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you want to do. Just some hint: you talk about a subdir /snippets but nothing in your code close to that. Another thing: you have a hard coded 'user_id' string in your href - why? If it is a typo and you want to put the content of user_id variable there, in this case you first had to add user_id to your context variable. Just questions.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of Information. I will add some now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed the issue. As often the answer was trivial.
I already tried including the subdirectory snippets into my return render like so:

```
return render(request, "snippets/friend_requests.html", context)
```

But that did not work.
In the end I just had to include the whole path from the top of my app template.
like so:

```
return render(request, "accounts/snippets/friend_requests.html", context)
```

Thanks to everyone who commented on this issue!